# How should you handle questions with answers in the comments?

Tags: discussion

I've seen this a few times where a question is asked, is answered within the comments but no official answer is posted or selected as the correct answer.

Example: [How can i Update My Product Export time consuming period for Bulk export products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125460/how-can-i-improve-my-product-export-time-duration-for-bulk-export-products)

I wasn't sure if I should close it, post the answer or if there is another way of handling this?

What should we do in a situation like this?

SR

EDIT: This ended up being a duplicate question, but I'd still like to know what to do in a situation like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens a lot on Stackoverflow, especially when the question is simple but the OP didn't realise until they worked it out.

In most cases if it's a typo or something small the question should be closed as such.

In cases where the question and answer are potentially useful in future, I normally leave a comment encouraging whoever posted the "answer/comment" to post it as an actual answer so the OP can accept it.

It's worth encouraging users to follow the process of the StackExchange sites - it helps with site statistics, pointing users to unanswered questions, *reputation* for users who deserve it as well as many other reasons (a la; the purpose of StackExchange!).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I close them as Unclear what youre asking (questions that went away on its own)

Sometimes I ask the answerer to post the comment as an answer.

Not sure what's the best solution I guess it depends for each case